# Excel VLOOKUP on multiple columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have one excel sheet - "Records_Table.xlsx" with the following data -

[image]

In my another excel sheet - "User_Input_Table.xlsx" ,

[image]

the user will input the Product and state, and the catalog number will be generated from the  "Records_Table.xlsx"

I am using vlookup formula - `VLOOKUP(A2,B2,[Records_Table.xlsx]records_sheet!$A$2:$B$50,3)`

but it is not showing any result, what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `INDEX("pull from this col",MATCH("matching this","from this col"))`

index/match is almost always better than vlookups

Comment: does the data need to be in sorted order, like in vlookup ?

Comment: Nope; and that's only [one](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/) of the advantages it has over vlookups

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a 'index' column (in both sheets) that concatenates multiple columns into 1 lookup column:

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(A2,B2),[Records_Table.xls]Sheet1!$C:$D,2,FALSE)
```

where $C is the new index column i.e. C2 = CONCATENATE(A2,B2) in User_input, and your lookup data starting from $D

[Manual Indexed VLookup sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5lqw.png)

Might be a hack, but I find it useful when doing a quick lookup on number of keys

Comment: simple and helpful.. nice thinking out of the box..+1

Comment: My colleagues used this on their spreadsheets and I've changed them all to MATCH/INDEX functions for a number of reasons: it's faster, takes up less space, no hidden/helper columns. Generally speaking this answer is by all means inferior